# Fixed width when scrolling horizantally

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar and material design theme but there is such problem that I can't handle when scrolling horizantally.

These are the problems' pictures;
[image]

When I try to scroll horizantally, this awful visual comes out;
[image]

Here is the CSS codes of the navigation bar;

[image] The red circle that I created is the problem. What I want is that when I scroll horizantally, that navigation bar should stay fixed and not scrolled. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code.  Thanks!

Comment: Posted! Thanks! @trav

Comment: Thanks for the effort there but if possible, please post the raw code here in the thread.  You can also copy and paste your code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and then post that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this CSS

```
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.body-of-content{
   overflow-x:auto;
   max-width:100%;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing a use case

https://jsfiddle.net/12md1fqh/

**SNIPPET**

```css
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.header{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:2em;
}
.data{
  width:200%;
  height:50px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.body-of-content{
  max-width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Header
</div>

<div class="body-of-content">
<div class="data">
I am scrollllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllableeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee !!
</div>
</div>
```